# Grails Generic Exception Handling Mechanism

Tags: exception, grails

I am a newbie in grails and trying to find a best way for exception handling in Grails. 
I am using Grails 2.4.2 with Spring Secxurity Core.

Following are the scenarios that needs to be considered.

Call to the Grails app could be Web Call/Ajax call/ RestFul call.

Response type expected could be a JSON/TEXT/XML/HTML

Exceptions could occur in any layer of the application(Filters, COntrollers, Service, Domain, TagLib, Database)

Proper HTTP Status code has to be set for the exception. (Could be same for all exceptions)

I want to have a least impact on the coding since grails reduces the boiler plate code a lot, i don't want to end up writing redundant codes in each controller.

Consider the above scenario's what could be the best possible approach on this.

Based on the format type( [Content-Negotiation](http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/guide/single.html#contentNegotiation) in Grails we could determine the Response Type that is to be provided). I was looking at the [traits way](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#controllerExceptionHandling)  of adding exception handling in the controller by implementing the traits for all controllers as defined in the Grails User Documentation. What would happen to the security exceptions that is being thrown by the Spring-Security.

When i make Ajax calls, I believe the error call back on the ajax client is determined by the status code of the HTTP Response code.

What I need is a way to forward any exceptions that occur to a generic error controller which should have access to the root cause, any messages associated with it and construct a HTML/TEXT/JSON/XML response out of it and render it to the client.

Is it possible to achieve this. Any inputs are highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance